# A sequence with no Cauchy subsequence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let   $E=\mathcal{C}([0,\pi],\mathbb{R})$ and $$d(f,g)=\sqrt{\int_0^{\pi} (f(x)-g(x))^2 dx}, ~\forall f,g\in E$$
Hello,

please How to prove that $f_n(x)=\sin(nx), n\in \mathbb{N}$ has no a Cauchy subsequence ?

Edit: $(f_{n_k})$ is a Cauchy subsequence iff $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists k_0\in\mathbb{N}, \forall p,q\in \mathbb{N}, p>q\geq n_0\Rightarrow d(f_{n_p},f_{n_q})<\varepsilon$

i know that for any $p',q'\in \mathbb{N}$ , $d(f_p',f_q')=\sqrt{\pi}$

can i put $n_p=p'$ and $n_q=q'$ ?

But is this means that the sequence is not Cauchy or that the sequence has no Cauchy subsequence ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried calculating $d(f_m, f_n)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes $d(f_n,f_m)=\sqrt{\pi}$ but this means that $(f_n)$ is not cauchy

Comment: Vrouvrou -- The constant norm of difference between *any* two distinct $f_n$ implies no Cauchy subsequence either, not just the whole thing not Cauchy.

Comment: @coffeemath so any sequence which is not a Cauchy sequence has no Cauchy subsequence ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou No, the point is that you have a uniform bound on $d(f_n,f_m)$ which doesn't depend on $n,m$ at all. This means that $d(f_{n_k},f_{n_\ell})$ can't be small either, regardless of which $n_k$ and $n_\ell$ you pick.

Comment: i don't understand you comment

Comment: @Vrouvrou $d(f_n,f_m)=\sqrt{\pi}$ for all $n,m$, so there can't be a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which is Cauchy because then still $d(f_{n_k},f_{n_\ell})=\sqrt{\pi}$. This does not mean that *no* non-Cauchy sequences have Cauchy subsequences, for instance all bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ have Cauchy subsequences.